# Stack overflow attempt on svchost.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, process-explorer, svchost

My computer detected a stack overflow attempt on svchost.  I looked at procexplorer and checked the hash of the svchost and it checked out.  My question is if a file is successful with a stack overflow on a svchost.exe will it change the hash of svchost?

Comment: No;  There is no risk to the file.  It cannot be changed.

Comment: So if the stack overflow is successful the hash doesn't change but the overflow attack still allows an arbitrary program to run?

Comment: You are confusing a stack overflow and a buffer overflow.